# How to make SCNSphere with a UIImage diffuse contents not care about lighting but simply show the original UIImage

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a global sphere to my scene which has a skybox image applied to it. The issue is the lighting in the scene directly impacts its presentation. I'd like the applied image to present exactly as designed; essentially lighting agnostic.

My assumption was I could modify the `SCNMaterial` to make this work but I can't figure out what settings I should use. My alternative solution is to add a ton of spot SCNLights to the scene and point them at the sphere. I'd like to avoid this.

```
let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 2000.0)
sphere.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "skybox")

let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
sphereNode.castsShadow = false
sphereNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
```

I know this can be solved with `SCNScene`s background.content but we're using an orthographic camera which disables the default skybox functionality. So, as an aside, if you know how to make the default skybox work with an orthographic camera that would also solve this problem. See [Using Cube Map Textures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents) for skybox specs.

Comment: Have you looked at the `lightingModel` property of `SCNMaterial`?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, skybox images work with an orthographic camera **only on-device**, not on-simulator. Perspective cameras allow skybox images to work on both simulator and device. We had assumed the simulator was okay to test on since the skybox image worked initially when we had a perspective camera.

**TL;DR** Running the app on a physical device shows the skybox for an orthographic camera; simulator does not.